# Load Custom View in Xib?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am beginner in iOS.I have created custom view and load into my xib

I am using below code but it is not working

```
let view = CustomView(self.view.bound)
self.view.addSubView(view)
```

Can anyone tell me how i can load view into xib?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it using below code

```
let customView =  NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CustomView
self.view.addSubview(menuView)
```